# Contents of Bins in Bin Packing Algorithm

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

For a Bin packing algorithm(I am using First-fit algorithm) we get output as number of bins, but I want to know the content of bins. How to do that?
for ex:=
Input:-

```
     number of items={8,1,4,2,1,4)
     capacity of bin=10
```

Output:-

```
      bin1={8,2}
      bin2={4,4,1,1}
```

Comment: What does your current implementation look like? What language is it? Can it not be trivially extended to also store contents apart from simply weights/volumes?

Comment: Also, please don't add unnecessary tags. It's unlikely you're coding this in both Java and C++. Ultimately, if you want real help, you'll need to show us what you've actually tried. We can't do your homework for you.